# Web app URL after npm start in Vagrant

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to run an Ubuntu box. This one specifically: [ubuntu/trusty64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64).

On my Windows host machine, I start up my web app by doing `npm start` then going to `localhost:8080` in my browser (I am using `webpack-dev-server`). I want to do something similar after starting it up inside vagrant.

Right now, I have a synced folder and my web app is placed in there. I can start up my app just fine inside the Ubuntu Vagrant box with `npm start`. However, I don't know how to view it. The Vagrant Ubuntu machine is set up on a private network defined inside the `Vagrantfile` (192.168.24.100). I am able to visit my Apache server that is set up in the Vagrant machine through that ip address.

I tried typing `192.168.24.100:8080`; however, I get "Unable to connect". How can I view my web app in my browser? Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**: I tried configuring the `forwarded_port` in the `Vagrantfile` like this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

But that still doesn't work.

---

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.24.100"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "web/", "/var/www/"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: Show us your Vagrantfile... at least where you're setting up the private networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a forwarded port to connect to your Vagrant box by its IP address.  The forwarded port is only so that you could access your VM from your host IP address.  At least for my workflow, I almost never do this.  It just leads to port conflicts when you have several Vagrant VMs running.  I prefer to access the Vagrant box directly, and use the vagrant-hosts plugin to update hosts file entries so I can access those boxes by name.

In any case, since your web server on port 80 is fine, the networking side of things is working.  Either your Node.js app isn't actually running, it isn't listening on port 8080, it isn't bound to the right interface (or all interfaces), or you have some firewall running.

Comment: When I start up my wep app, it says it is running here: `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server`. I replaced `localhost` with the configured ip in the browser but I get "Unable to connect". I wait for it build successfully before I try to visit the app. I turned my firewall off to be completely sure and still no luck. I'm guessing I have to forward the port? I noticed when I start up the machine with `vagrant up`, it says `default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)`. So I need to do make it do the same with `8080`?

Comment: @m.o You didn't show us your app code, but if the message is correct (and it often isn't), it's bound to localhost on the VM.  You need to change your listen code to bind to `::` or `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`.  What does your `.listen()` look like in your app?

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the listen address in `webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js` to `0.0.0.0`. It works when I go to port `8080` now.